# Get reference to custom UISlider

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, uislider

I have implemented a custom class of UISlider so the touchable areas are larger

Everything is working great except now I want to change the initial values depending on other factors in the app.

The only code I have gets the slider's ID from (sender)

I need to address the slider like so...

```
slider.value = 25.0;
```

But the only code I have is

```
-(IBAction) slider1Changed:(id) sender{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) sender;
    int progressAsInt =(int)(slider.value);
    NSLog(@"Slider is %@",slider);
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setInteger:progressAsInt forKey:@"SharedSkilledWorkforce"];
}
```

In the xib @property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *slider1; doesn't show up as a conncetion

How do I address the custom UISlider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding IBOutlet to your slider1 property?

This:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *slider1;
```

Needs to be:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *slider1;
```

in order to show up in IB.  IBOutlet is a hint to the designer similar to IBAction.

Comment: It's not like I haven't been doing iOS for a year now. Doh! Soooooo stoopid of me... thank you!